# How to E2E test handling of an unknown error in a client-server application?

Tags: testing, error-handling

Using a ton of libraries, IO, ... you cannot handle all imaginary errors.
You will need some form of "catch uncaught exception" handling to still have a control flow for such a case.
But if you are aware of such an error, you usually can and want to add a proper handling.

That brings up the paradoxical question of how one would go about testing the handling of an unknown error.

**Having a test case for the handling of an unknown error would make it a known error and would trigger adding appropriate handling, which in turn will invalidate the test case.**

How should we test the handling of an unknown error?

One thought process was to specifical implement a method which can be triggered by some internally known condition which will raise an "unknown exception".
But this feels wrong on so many levels.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If such handling is done by catching an exception, simply catch a top-level exception and in the test suite force the "throwing" method to throw this top-level exception, to ensure you actually have a catch block for it. I do not think anything else can be done about this.

Comment: Important detail missing in my question: We need to cover this as an e2e test. So no access to internal methods. :( But I see your point! Maybe we can make this work (in terms of it being acceptable that this is not covered end-to-end but on a unit test level).

Comment: What kind of E2E test is this? Client application request against an API, which handles the exception? I.e. the tested client and server are separate apps?

Comment: It is a client-server application but E2E would be test execution from the client perspective (which will include the execution in the backend).

Comment: `handling an unknown error would make it a known error` by this rationale, your question is not answerable.

Comment: It's unclear what actual problem you are trying to solve here. Why do you think end to end testing of unknown errors is important to your system?

Comment: I feel like there is a specific testing strategy that focuses on simulating error conditions that would be useful in your case, but I cannot for the life of me remember what it is called. Years ago Netflix released a suite of tools used to simulate network issues in their micro services. Not really sure if that pertains to you, though.

Comment: I personally would not cover this by E2E test at all, simple as that. If you want to test against that scenario, I would create: 1) unit test to verify exception is caught and handled in an expected manner, leading to a specific outcome with a given contract, 2) test to verify the outcome is correctly serialized to server response, 3) write test against mock web server returning response of the "error" contract and ensuring it is handled correctly on client side. You have full coverage this way, without the necessity of E2E testing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's important to our system since an unknown error will lead to an error report send to the customer system. It's a medical application and the customer system is a third-party medical archiving system. So we are simply regulatory wise required to cover this via an E2E test.

Comment: @Andy The issue is that we have a microservice architecture and the unknown error can happen in any component which leads to a chain of events. One component picking up that another component did not finish. Writing of error states. Generation of error reports. Sending of reports to customers. etc. And all this needs to go hand in hand in case of such an event. That's what the E2E test is supposed to test.
Unit tests will not cover this.
One option, you seem to hint at, might be to cover it via contract testing.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Sounds interesting.

Comment: Create a new `TestTheErrorHandlingError` and throw that when in test mode? if using HTTP you could add a new parameter or header `https://blah/blah/blah?blah=blah&__fake_error=DogCaughtTheCarException`

Comment: Contract testing is exactly what I was hinting at. We also implement microservices at the company I current work for, high 10s of microservices running in production environment, and we cover these scenarios exactly by testing the contracts between the systems. If you can ensure the contracts match and are (de)serialized to/from target language objects, you can then simply treat the entire microservice ecosystem as one big system and write unit test for each business logic part.

Answer (score 1):

> That brings up the paradoxical question of how one would go about testing the handling of an unknown error.
>
> Having a test case for the handling of an unknown error would make it a known error and would trigger adding appropriate handling, which in turn will invalidate the test case.

I don't see a paradox here. You don't simply remove a test because someone added error handling logic. If you stumble across an error condition that was not previously encountered, you need to have a conversation with developers and management about how this situation should be handled. Sure, you discovered it. Now you wrote a test. Record the expected result, which is the application throws an error, crashes, etc. If this is unacceptable, then requirements need to be defined to handle this.

After an unknown error condition is handled, your old test is likely outdated. The test should be updated to assert the new, expected error handling behavior. Like you said, what was unknown has now become known.

This pattern of testing and discovery is known as [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). It really is a form of experimentation where the tester makes no assumptions about how the system is supposed to work, or how people are supposed to use it. Black-box testing can uncover these "unknown errors". Write a test. Define how the application should behave. Supplement with [white-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) once you understand the internals that allow this error to surface.

There is no paradox. What you are describing is a name for something. The important thing is you communicate what happened, how you encountered it, and have a conversation with the relevant development and management people to determine how this should be handled.

Be aware that their answer could legitimately be "we won't handle it."

Comment: Let's say we cannot find any new unknown errors (because we fixed them all). Then how are we going to test the "unknown error handling"?

Comment: @Spenhouet: by utilizing black-box testing. You basically guess. You try things out. You experiment on your system. You can also utilize white-box testing, which affords you some knowledge of internals so you can simulate things like, what if a database operation succeeds but a subsequent file operation fails? You will need to research testing strategies, with a focus on black and white-box testing.

Comment: That’s a case for mocking. With mocking you can get any errors. However, you can’t have case specific handling or fix the problem. You can just put everything that is unexpected into the category “unexpected error”.